# Internal error in the expression evaluator when remote debugging msvsmon.exe VS2015 or unable to attach to the process. the rpc server is unavailable

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2015, remote-debugging, visual-studio-debugging

System in written in `C#`, `.Net4.5`. I am trying to remote debug one of our Web APIs. I am using `msvsmon.exe` (2015) on server and running `Visual Studio 2015` on my local.

I can connect to process no problem and breakpoints are being hit, I am also sure I am running same version of code as I manually copied over `dll` and `pdb` files from my local machine to the server.

I can't even inspect strings when they are fired into endpoint I get `Internal error in the expression evaluator`. To remedy this error [offered solution is to tick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21854426/get-internal-error-in-the-expression-evaluator-on-add-watch-function-when-tr) the box on `Managed Compatibility Mode` in `Tools -> Options -> Debugging` however, when I do this, when I try to attach to process in debug window, I get `unable to attach to the process. the rpc server is unavailable`. Solution to which [offered is to untick that same box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15009901/remote-debugging-not-working-unable-to-attach-to-process-the-rpc-server-is-no), lol.

I have also [tried in vain to enable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34545354/internal-error-in-the-expression-evaluator) `Use the legacy C# and VB expression evaluators` in debug options but that didn't do any good.

I am sure someone by now have ran into this problem....
**How do I inspect objects when remote debugging on VS2015?**

Comment: Common question.  You've tried all the known workarounds, there aren't anymore.  What they basically do is bypass the new VS2015-specific code in the debugging engine.  It is very buggy, the price of agile, work on it gets [postponed repeatedly](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/9853).  All you can do next is call Microsoft Support.  Fwiw, you ought to take that RPC error a little more serious.  Might well be the underlying problem with the expression evaluator.  Environmental issue, disable anti-malware and firewall and whatever other shovelware wants to network.

Comment: @Matas Vaitkevicius, what about this issue? Could you share us the latest information about this issue?

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT There isn't any information, I simply added insane amount of oldschool logging that writes to text files and solved my issues that way....

Answer (score 0):

I met the error "unable to attach to the process. the rpc server is unavailable" before which was related to the firewall, like Hans Passant's suggestion, you could test it again after you close/disable the firewall or other third party tools. Of course, you could also add your VS Devenv.exe to the Firewall allow list like this thread, debug it again.

https://cerkit.com/2014/08/12/remote-debugging-issue-with-asp-net-unable-to-attach-to-the-process/